# using .append option to an array end with an error in Swift/Playground

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I'm studying Swift and having trouble at appending value to an exist array,
I'm using Xcode 6.1/Yosemite10.10

my code at Playground is

```
import UIKit
var someText = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
someText = someText.append("ddd")
```

I'm expecting that someText holds ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"] but Xcode gives me
an error: '()' is not compatible to '[String]'

Please someone teach me what is wrong here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now I got it all clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're attempting to assign the return value of the append function to your array, and the return value is Void, not [String]. All you have to do is this:

```
var someText = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
someText.append("ddd")
```